Containerized Rust builds and rust-analyzer
I'm setting up a development environment where all build tooling and compilation happens inside a Docker container, but source editing is done on the host machine. The source code is mapped to the host filesystem, and the container runs cargo watch to pick up changes near-instantly, and engineers don't need to install any Rust tooling locally. The goal is to have a devstack experience where the developer simply installs Docker, their favorite IDE, and nothing else. Since the "dev stack" is comprised of microservices each written in a different language, all those microservices come with their own containerized development setup, and the developer doesn't need to install build toolchain necessary to work on each microservice.
However, I’m running into a challenge with rust-analyzer. Is there any way to run it inside the Docker container while still allowing the host IDE to communicate with it? I would very much prefer not to map the target/ directory onto the host, and not to run rust-analyzer on the host, but have the IDE communicate with it across the container boundary.
Any insights would be greatly appreciated!

I don’t understand why you would choose this setup over simple dev containers. Either way, you want devs to use their favorite IDE, which would mean that any extension of that IDE that interacts with rust analyzer must be supported by your solution. What happens if IDE 1 support remote rust analyzer and IDE 2 doesn’t support such setup? Are you going to limit the amount of IDEs for your devs? If so, please use dev containers. All you need is Docker and VSCode.

@JarroVGIT I don't quite understand why your solution to let everyone use the IDE of their choice is everybody must use VSCode.

@cafce25 my point is the exact opposite of that. The OP claimed he wanted every dev to be able to use their favorite IDE. My point was that would be infeasible anyway, and if you are (inevitably) limiting the amount of IDEs which you support, then why not limit it all the way down to just 1.
